# Unable to generate release builds Android Studio Bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio

Unable to generate release builds on Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1

I have macOS 12.2, Gradle version 7.0.4, Intel processor

Do anyone solved the issue? Ideas?

The issue is not reproductible on Arctic Fox

**UPDATE:**

*It is a gradle 7.0.4 issue, Upgrading to 7.1.1 solves the issue*

Comment: You need to include more details if you want help.  I can definitely confirm Android Studio Bumblebee can build release versions in general.

Comment: i am running in macOS latest version Intel processor

Comment: @possum - I found the fix by myself. It is Gradle 7.0.4 issue, after upgrading to 7.1.1 the problem vanishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue by using AGP version 7.0.2 but was able to fix it after upgrading to 7.1.0

Comment: After upgrading the Gradle version from 7.0.4 to 7.1.1 I was able to generate release builds